# How can I limit the size of incoming information when using 'GET' for XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a JS script that makes a call to a URL which holds a changelog text file, and it reads the text contents of the URL and displays version info for me.

I would like to limit the information received from the GET request to 1000 bytes. Currently, it returns the entire list of text, then uses a regex expression to filter out what I need. My question is, how can I limit the size of the incoming information to 1000 bytes?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
            var response = this.responseText;
            var regEx = /^[^)]+\)/;
            var match = regEx.exec(response);
            if(match){
                var vers = match[0];
                console.log(vers);
            } else{
                console.log('no match');
            }
            document.getElementById("version").innerHTML = vers;
        }
    }
    //FIX! Have changelog be passed into parameter
    if (window.location.href === "abc123.com/hello") {
        xhr.open('GET', 'https://static.abc123.com/hello/changelog.txt', true);
    }
```

Comment: You can't control what server sends from client. Need to set up server side script to send limited amount of the file

Comment: Take a look at the [xmlhttrequest progress event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent). You can monitor the amount of data received and abort the transfer when you have enough. Of course, if it's the last 1000 bytes you want this won't help. It's probably better to do this server-side and just send the data you want.

Comment: @ReddHerring Thank you! Checking this out now. I was looking to get the beginning 1000 bytes. Sorry if I worded that wrong.

Comment: Another possibility is an [HTTP Range request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) if your server supports it. This will require you to add extra headers to your request and handle 206 Partial Content responses.

Comment: @ReddHerring The HTTP Range request was the best way to do this! I really appreciate your help. The only line that I had to add was:

xhr.setRequestHeader('Range', 'bytes=0-1000');